# No se me genera mas de una foto del feed de instagram

Tags: javascript, api, instagram

estoy utilizando la api de instagram, y al obtener las url y intentar insertarlas en el html desde

javascript solo se logra renderizar una imagen a la vez, no logro descifrar el porque adjunto

codigo:

```
   const getAll = async () => {
try {
    let res = await axios.get(`${url2}`)
        json = await res.data;
        console.log(res , json)
    json.data.forEach(e => {
        console.log(e.media_url)
        document.body.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${e.media_url}" class="fotos">
        `
    });

  } catch (err) {
    let mensaje = err.statusText || "Ocurrio un error";
  }
}
```

el problema se da al querer renderizar las imagenes, porque puedo obtener todo lo que le solicito

a la api

```
   <img class="fotos" src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885- 
    15/84094168_488049961824045_4403680624229952769_n.jpg? 
    _nc_cat=108&amp;ccb=1-7&amp;_nc_sid=8ae9d6&amp;_nc_ohc=-VF8CjJlQ- 
    cAX9Pjn4D&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.
    cdninstagram.com&amp;edm=ANo9K5cEAAAA&amp;oh=0 
   0_AT_LTiEfSe5vom-M4QCQL7TUNtqy0XQf1Ntkd2M0ywy_ZA&amp;oe=62A75E94">
   <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/B86Ou6igP1J/">Foto</a>
```

esto ultimo es lo que renderiza, pero solo de un enlace, cuando deberian ser 10

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega todo el HTML que genera. Saludos. PD: `<img src="${e.media_url}" class="fotos"/>` (mira al final)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "resultado";
```

entonces, en cada iteración, solo va a ir un "resultado" en document.body.innerHTML.

Por lo tanto... Debería existir un append/forma para llevar el valor previo y añadir lo que viene, algo como:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + resultado ;
```

Como dato adicional, la apertura de un elemento HTML requiere un cierre del mismo.

Intenta con esto:

```
const getAll = async () => {
try {
    let res = await axios.get(`${url2}`)
        json = await res.data;
        console.log(res , json)
    json.data.forEach(e => {
        console.log(e.media_url)
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + `
            <img src="${e.media_url}" class="fotos"/>
        `
    });

  } catch (err) {
    let mensaje = err.statusText || "Ocurrio un error";
  }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias esto me sirvio

Comment: Marca la respuesta como aceptada. Click en el check del costado. Esto ayuda a mantener la buena salud del sitio, efecto del porcentaje de preguntas resueltas. Saludos.